# Can't bind on current item in QML view/model

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a simple task: need to output some information about current item of ListView separately. For example, in outside Label, but I can't succeed.

I figured out that problem related to where model was defined. If it is separate object with id this behavior happened. But when I define it inlined inside the view, all works fine. This behaviour is very weird and looks like a bug.

To make this code work, just switch to commented model definition. Anybody encounter this problem or may be know something?

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

import Qt.labs.calendar 1.0


ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480

    visible: true

    CalendarModel {
        id: myModel

        from: new Date(2018, 0, 1)
        to: new Date(2018, 11, 31)
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Label {
            id: myLabel
            text: "myLabel1"
        }

        Label {
            text: myModel.monthAt(myView.currentIndex)
        }

        ListView {
            id: myView

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal
            highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
            boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

            model: myModel

//            model:  CalendarModel {
//                id: myModel

//                from: new Date(2018, 0, 1)
//                to: new Date(2018, 11, 31)
//            }

            delegate: Rectangle {
                color: "green"
                width: myView.width
                height: 200

                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: model.month
                }
            }

            onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                console.log(currentIndex)
                myLabel.text = String(currentIndex)
            }

            ScrollIndicator.horizontal: ScrollIndicator {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: suggestion: provide a [mcve]

Comment: So, what is your question? What were you trying to do and what didn't work out?

Comment: I see that your code works correctly, what is the problem?

Comment: As I said, info from current item in model not showing in Label. I uncommented right now not working part to make it more obvious.

Comment: @tr1cks You will say currentIndex, the currentItem refers to an Item. I see that the currentIndex does work correctly.

Comment: @eyllanesc Doesn't matter a lot here. Do you try code from my last edit and don't reproduce the problem?

Comment: Looks like a XY problem. I think that the problem arose from a misunderstanding. First of all the Qt documentation says that `CalendarModel` used as a model for a `ListView` that uses `MonthGrid` as a delegate, not `Rectangle`. So index in this case id a month number, at least as I see that. You didn't change the curentIndex so what do you expect to get? At program start it should be 0.

Comment: @folibis the problem is weird, I do not think the problem is in the delegate, but if a model is created directly in the view: `model: CalendarModel{...}` 
it works correctly, but if the model is created in the same QML and then assigned: `CalendarModel{ id: myModel ...} .. model: myModel` 
it does not work

Comment: @eyllanesc Yep, it's the point. Playing with minimal example was good idea, thx.

Comment: @tr1cks 
I recommend you edit your question to indicate as I have indicated. I could only get that conclusion after trying your code. Your approach to the problem is not good.

Comment: I fail to reproduce the problem, but if I could, I would expect it to be a bug that should go to https://bugreports.qt.io

Comment: @derM What version of Qt you used?

Comment: @tr1cks As derM points out, report it as a bug